# Having trouble using if statement with for loop and arrays

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I am having an issue in one of my functions. Here is the code:

```
include <stdio.h>
include <math.h>
include <stdlib.h>

int inputAmount(int i);

void inputFahrs(double data[ ], int j);

double fahrToCels (double data[ ], int j);

void  outputFahrs(double data [ ], int numFahrs);

void outputAverage(double data[ ], int numFahrs);

void outputHighLows(double data[ ], int numFahrs);

void outputGrads(double data[ ], int numFahrs);

int main (void)
{
    int i, j, numFahrs;
    double data[i], *ptr=&data[i];
    i=inputAmount(i);
    printf("%d\n\n", i);
    inputFahrs(&data[i], i);
    data[j]=fahrToCels(&data[i], j);
    printf("%.1f", data[j]); 
    return 0;
}

int inputAmount(int i)
{
    printf("Please enter the amount of vaues you would like to use.\n\n");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    while(i<1 || i>25)
    {
        printf("Value is out of range. Please enter another value.\n\n");
        scanf("%d", &i);
    }       
    return i;
}   

void inputFahrs(double data[ ], int i)
{
    int j;
    printf("Please enter temperature values in the range of -175 to 175 degrees F.\n\n");
    for(j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        scanf("%f", &data[j]);
        if (data[j]< -175 || data[j]>175)
        {
            printf("Temperature value is out of range. Please re-enter");
            scanf("%f", &data[j]);
        }
    }       
}

double fahrToCels (double data[ ], int j)
{
    int i;
    printf("TEST");
    for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
    {
        data[i]=(((data[i])-32)*(5.0/9.0));
    }
    return data[i];
}
```

Basically the issue in my code is that it skips the `if` statement entirely. I want the program to go through the `for` loop and if the user enters a value out of range, I want the `if` statement to start. A print statement inside the `for` loop but after the `if` statement works fine so it is definitely something wrong with that. I have also tried a `while` loop in place of the `if`.

Comment: Little Obj-C going on in this code.

Comment: The condition on its own seems alright, but you really need to check the indices. Another point is that you don't need to get a new input inside the if statement, decrementing `j` should be enough.

Comment: `i` is not initialized btw. [This code results in an infinite loop for me](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2gWpzh$20).

Answer (score 0):

the problem is  you are iterating the loop with

> j

and checking the condition with subscript

> i

using j as a subscript will work

> scanf("%f",&data[ j ])
>
> if(data[ j ]< -175] | | data[ j ]>175)

should work. since data[i] is not a possible subscript value, since i is the array size

and why have you used the line

```
data[i]=data[i];
```

?

Comment: i,j is a problem. But it input data into data[i], and compare data[i] in if statement. So your answer doesn't hit the real problem.

Comment: the problem is data[i] does not exist, since there are only subscripts from 0 to i-1, since i is the size of the array

Comment: @EvanLi: `data[i]` is not a valid memory location since it's outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: But C doesn't check array boundary. If this is a single threaded program, data[i] is usable although it's overflow the valid array memory.

Comment: Sorry i should have mentioned this. i is the size of my array tha is scanned in, in a previous function. Thats why i have the for loop using j and i. It counts up to the i that was previously determined.

Comment: @EvanLi: Though array boundary is not checked, there is no place for the scanf function to store the input value. so this error

Comment: "there is no place for the scanf function to store the input value" this statement is wrong again. data[i] is just 8 bytes after the data[] array.

Comment: That was why I had used the data[i]=data[i] I had hope that it may store the value into the array for the if statement but clearly not.

Comment: ya it cannot store, since that memory location does not exist

Comment: Replacing i with j for the data[ ] yeilds the same result for me, it just continnues accepting values until the array size is reached

Comment: No luck with the above code posted. It may be an error on my part so I thank the user and you gys for posting. Even with the above code it still doesnt do anything when entering something out of range.

Comment: @user2214010: can you post the whole of your code? with the main function?

Comment: use data instead of &data[i] at the inputFahrs call statement

Comment: "If this is a single threaded program, data[i] is usable although it's overflow the valid array memory" -- Uh, no.

Comment: using &data[i] sends only the address of the data[i], which is not an array, but an address. so, using "data" is enough

Comment: I see that changing it to data allows me to not use a pointer which is nice. Thanks for that tip.

Answer (score 0):

```
void inputFahrs(float data[],int i)
{
    int j;
    printf("Please Enter values in the range of -175 to 175\n");
    for(j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
            scanf("%f",&data[j]);
            if(data[j]<-175 || data[j]>175)
            {
                    printf("value is out of range. Enter correct value\n");
                    j--;
            }
    }
}
```

this one works fine

Comment: How are you even reaching this function? [This code results in an infinite loop for me](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2gWpzh%2420).

Comment: @AnishRam: you have done the same mistake. used &data[i] in the call statement instead of just `data`

Comment: Please delete this answer and combine it with your previous one.

Answer (score -1):

I guess that this is because you are scanning and storing data using the `i` index, which is the size of the array passed to the function, not the index of the current element, which is stored in `j`. It should be:

```
   scanf("%f", &data[j]);
   ..
```

In addition, why do you compare in your for loop `j <= i - 1`? `j < i` sounds simpler.